# ADF for mobile: Can we split the amx page into parts for different purposes?

Tags: android, view, oracle-adf-mobile

I am creating an app in ADF. I want to split the view in 2 parts, i.e,

one part which will have images and buttons,
second part where the browser will be opened on a button click.
I tried using panel group layout and panel form layout. But nothing works.

I am totally new in ADF. How shall I split the screen in 2 parts?  Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: There's a panel splitter component you can use to achieve this.

Comment: According to my knowledge about Panel Splitter, it works just like a Navigation Drawer. And I want to split the AMX page in 2 parts, no drawer kind of thing.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. Like 2 amx pages in one page?